# DES Encryption in Node.js

Tags: java, node.js, encryption, des

I've been trying to port this Java Program to Node.js. I've tried a few ways and still unable to get this done so far. Could be due to my limited knowledge in Cryptography.

The Node.js Program I've written is this.

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var iv = crypto.randomBytes(8);

var encrypt = function(data, key) {
    var decodeKey = crypto.createHash('sha512').update(key, 'utf-8').digest().slice(0, 24);
    var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('des-ede-cbc', decodeKey, iv);
    return cipher.update(data, 'utf8', 'hex') + cipher.final('hex');
};

var data = 'abc101'
var key = '1785851816255252-8887772';

var cipher = encrypt(data, key);
console.log(cipher);
```

I keep receiving the following error:

```
Error: Invalid key length
```

The original program I am trying to port is this:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.DESedeKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class PasswordEncryptor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String passwd = "abc101";
        String msgId = "1785851816255252-8887772";

        String result = "";

        try {
            if (passwd == null && passwd.equals("") && msgId == null && msgId.equals("")) {
                System.out.println("Wrong Inputs");
            } else {
                result = PasswordEncryptor.encryptPassword(msgId, passwd);
            }
            System.out.println(result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in PasswordEncryption  ::: " + e);
        }

    }

    public static String encryptPassword(String msgId, String password) {
        String finalValue = "";
        try {
            MessageDigest mDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
            byte[] digestSeed = mDigest.digest(msgId.getBytes());
            byte[] seedEncArray = Arrays.copyOf(digestSeed, 24);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            SecretKeySpec skspec = new SecretKeySpec(seedEncArray, "DESede");
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skspec, iv);
            byte[] finalByteArray = cipher.doFinal(password.getBytes());
            finalValue = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(finalByteArray));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in encryptPassword ::::" + e);
        }
        return finalValue;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

nodejs calls OpenSSL, whose naming schemes have some odd warts due to hysterical raisins. `des-ede-$mode` in OpenSSL is actually [Keying Option 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES#Keying_options), aka 2-key TDEA. For 'real' 3-key TDEA you must ask for `des-ede3-$mode` in this case `des-ede3-cbc`.

Also the Java code uses `new byte[8]` for the IV value, which is 8 bytes all zero, but your nodejs code uses random bytes. Random is actually better cryptographically, but if your goal is to produce the same results as the Java code you need to replicate its mistake.

Finally the Java code encodes the result in base64 while your nodejs code uses hex. These are semantically equivalent and easily interconvertible, but are not the same. If you do want the same, nodejs does support base64.

Aside: the attempted error check in the Java code

```
 if (passwd == null && passwd.equals("") && msgId == null && msgId.equals(""))
```

is just stupid; no Java `String` can be `== null` and `.equals("")` simultaneously. All those `&&` log-and should be `||` log-or. This code has clearly not been written *or* tested *or* reviewed competently; if I were you (which I'm not) I would avoid having anything to do with it.